# Covering an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by a countable collection of rectangles

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I'm reading *Analysis of Manifolds* by Munkres, and here is Lemma 16.2 in the book: 
Let $\mathcal{A}$ a collection of open sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and A be their union.  Then $\exists$ a countable collection {$Q_k:k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$} of rectangles s.t.

1. {$Q_k^o:k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$} covers A

   $\forall k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, $\exists B \in \mathcal{A}$ s.t. $Q_k \subseteq B$

   $\forall x \in A$, $\exists$ a neighborhood U of x that only intersects finitely many {$Q_k:k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$}.

Now Munkres is kind enough to provide a proof, which I am fine with.  But I have also read through the general topology part of his book *Topology* (that is, the 1st 8 chapters), and my question is how to prove the above result using facts from there.  The reason is I suspect there are powerful topology facts that we can use to simplify the proof.

Here are some observations I have made so far:

- A is an open set

  The condition (3) above says {$Q_k:k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$} is *locally finite*

  It's enough for {$Q_k^o:k \in \mathbb{Z}^+$} to be locally finite, since Munkres shows if $\mathcal{B}$ is a locally finite collection, then so is {$\bar{B}:B \in \mathcal{B}$}.

  A is metrizable, so it's *paracompact*. Thus, the open cover $\mathcal{A}$ of A has a locally finite open *refinement* $\mathcal{B}$, meaning $\forall B \in \mathcal{A}$, $\exists B^\prime \in \mathcal{B}$ s.t. $B^\prime \subseteq B$.

  I need to figure out somehow how to involve rectangles of $\mathbb{R}^n$, since a locally finite refinement of $\mathcal{A}$ need not consist of open rectangles.

  I know that the collection of all open rectangles forms a basis for the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}^n$, this is my only intuition for how to introduce rectangles.

Any help is much appreciated.